LibDeflateNET library compression for .NET 4.8
I have difficulties trying to instantiate compressor from LibDeflate.NET library:
using (var compressor = new DeflateCompressor(5)) {}


Error during compression: Unable to load DLL 'libdeflate': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

Under .NET Core and higher, runtime libraries are copied to the subfolder:

I took 32 bit version of libdeflate.dll and placed in the Debug directory. Still it cannot find it. However if I take 64 bit one, then it says it is the wrong image. So .. it reads 32 bit but for some reason doesn't want to load it.
Everything under .NET 6.0 (tested before) works as expected.

If libdeflate.dll requires a dependency that could not be found, you'll see this error too.

I know some nuget packages that use native dlls have issues on .Net framework. Changing to "SDK-style" projects may help. You could also use tools like Dependency walker and/or process monitor to try to figure out why the dll could not be loaded.

I wonder what's the point of using some wrapper over some native library if there is ZipFile? (check namespace for more options)

@Sinatr Speed. Definitely speed. 14 GB I can compress using deflate stream in about 3 minutes.

@JonasH, it turned out that the library libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll was missing. How is it possible that this library was not necessary under .NET 6.0?

@John Have you checked that it was not included in Net 6? As mentioned, the newer dotnet toolchain handle transitive dependencies better. And you can gain some of the benefits by updating the project structure, while keeping the same target framework.
